# How can I remap Vim keys with numbers?

Tags: key-bindings

I transitioned to Dvorak so now I'm remapping the keys on Vim.

One of the decisions are remap `q` to `d`, so I wrote the following on `~/.config/nvim`

```
noremap q d 
noremap qq dd
noremap Q D
noremap qt dk
noremap qh dj
noremap qw dw
noremap qe de
noremap q0 d0
noremap q$ d$
```

However, this doesn't work if you use a number, such as `q2w`. Typing `q` makes the editor waiting, and then typing `2` triggers a single delete, and then typing `w` just moves the cursor.

It is practically unfeasible to map every number combination (`q3w`, `q4w`, etc...). Is there any way to remap all the number combinations together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is have "q" work like "d" when you enter Normal mode commands then you can use the `'langmap'` setting.

```
:set langmap=qd,QD
```

Now `q2w` will work exactly the same as `d2w`. The mapping is also applied in Visual mode. In all other modes nothing changes, "q" is "q".

See `:h lmap` because there are a couple potentially important details (e.g. what to do if there is any interference with any of your mappings.)

There are reams of information out there on using Vim with a Dvorak keyboard, BTW. The [Vim Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Vim_with_the_Dvorak_keyboard_layout) is one example.

Comment: Strangely, while this works in neovim, the `q` key suddenly stopped working in vim... How can I know what is leading to it?

Comment: Not sure...I don't see any issues with vim. Do you have any mappings (e.g. using `nmap`) that might be conflicting? You can set `langmap` when all your other config is disabled (`vim -u NONE -N ....`) and see if problem still exists.

Comment: Seems that I set `noremap d h` on `~/.vimrc` and now the `q` is remapped to `h` as well. (so if I type in `q`, it moves the cursor to left). Do you know any workaround?

Comment: Did you read the help for `'langmap'` like I suggested? They talk about mapping conflicts in there.